# MVC WCF Validation

Tags: asp.net-mvc, wcf, validation, razor, service

I want to validate my view but I don't know what is best way to do it

I want to know if there is an option like this  in my service i have

```
 [Required(ErrorMessage = "Property is required.")]
 [DataMember]  
 public string Name { get; set; }
```

and when i pass to view data I want

```
@Html.Label("Name")
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name)
```

But can't find any solution in net so I think the answer is no so can some tell me what is the best solution to validate ?

Comment: Did you check this link: http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/455798/Server-side-Input-Validation-using-Data-Annotation and also this: http://www.dotnet-tricks.com/Tutorial/mvc/D8I4270712-MVC-Data-Annotations-for-Model-Validation.html

Comment: Yes but don't found solution for this case